# Having issues running the result of an Xargs find to get version of found items

Tags: find, xargs, locate

I'm able to return the path to the java executable but what i really want is the version of java so want to run the path returned with **-version** attached to the end.

Any help appreciated.

```
locate -b '\java' | xargs -ri  find {} -prune -type f -executable
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here was the eventual answer.

```
locate -b '\java' | xargs -ri  find {} -prune -type f -executable | xargs  bash -c '$0 -version'
```

````
 java version "1.6.0_41"
 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.13) (rhel-1.13.13.1.el6_8-x86_64)
 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.41-b41, mixed mode)```
````